# how can I write R to get data from each worksheets of all workbooks

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have been working on getting a data of each sheets from every files in the working directory. Here's my code.
I think I managed to load all worksheets in every workbooks into R, now it comes to the part to write a data.frame and export to csv.

It turned out that only data in every sheets in the LAST WORKBOOK R has loaded were written in .csv, not every sheets in EVERY workbook, but only LAST workbook. 
The problem must rose from the part where I out in DF[ws, ] <-c(shts1[ws],P).
But  as far as I checked, f<- length(shts1) should be the sum of the number of worksheets of every workboooks, but f is only the number of sheets of the last workbook in the folder.

Can anyone offer a helping hand?

Thank you

```
library(XLConnect)
setwd("D:\\R test\\")
files <- (Sys.glob("*.xls"))
#for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  wb1 <- loadWorkbook(file.path(files[i],sep=""))
  shts1 <- getSheets(wb1)
  #shts1
 f<- length(shts1)
  DF <- data.frame(txt=rep("", f),num=rep(NA, f),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  for (ws in 1:f) {    
    dat <- readWorksheet(wb1, ws)
    B<-as.data.frame.matrix(dat)
    P<-B[which(apply(B, 1, function(x) any(grepl("P", x)))),which(apply(B, 2, function(x) any(grepl("P", x))))+4]
DF[ws, ] <-c(shts1[ws],P)
  }
}
write.csv(DF, "prices.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: `DF <- data.frame(txt=rep("", f),...` Your loop is creating a blank data frame at each pass. So the information you add to it is deleted soon after until the end.

Comment: If you want a big data frame at the end with information from all workbooks and sheets, you have to create a DF for each workbook and put them together before writing to file.

Comment: Do you realize that you are overwriting your `DF` every time you read a new file? Of course it will contain only data from the last workbook, that's exactly how you coded it. As I offered in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402461/how-to-write-r-to-loop-each-worksheet-of-every-files-in-the-set-directory/), please provide some information on your expected output based on a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can give more relevant assistance.

Comment: Yes, I kinda suspected that DF is overwritten. The expected output is that sheetnames of ever sheets in every workbooks in teh directory is in column A and the datas "P" corresponding to each sheetnames in col A is showing in column B.